# django count data from model and show it on template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to count all the data and show it as a number on the template.

here my `models.py`

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here my `views.py`

```
class EmployeeListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'employees'
    model = models.Employee
```

my `employee.html`

```
 <h5 class='margin-bottom'>Total Data {{ employee_set.count }}</h5>
```

trying use `_set.count` but din't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `{{employees.count}}` as you are passing that through `context_object_name`.
It is a queryset on which you can use `count()` method.

Comment: thank you, its work. I forgot that `context_object_name`